# R help to fix issue

Tags: r

I am trying to create a histogram that will summarize the distribution of second finger length for males who answered question s22 with either 2 or 4. I am experiencing errors where it says invalid breaks, how do I fix this

Comment: To give a [good reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), it is helpful to provide some of your data via `dput(head(df))`, then edit and paste the result into your question.

Comment: Your filter is incorrect, try this instead `mydata1$gender == 'male' & ( mydata1$s22 =='2' | mydata1$s22 == '4')`.  You want an OR and not an AND between the =2 & =4 part.

Comment: As already mentioned it would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

OP's last edit of the question (as of 2021-07-03 03:55Z) shows the code

```
s22_2or4_male <- mydata1$second[mydata1$gender == 'male' & mydata1$s22 =='2' | mydata1$s22 == '4']
  
hist(mydata1$second[s22_2or4_male])
```

which has several issues:

1. Because of the precedence of the `&` operator and missing parantheses around the *or* clause, the logical expression will select *males* with `s22 == 2` as well as all other rows with `s22 == 4` *regardless of gender*.
2. `s22_2or4_male` already contains the selected values of column `mydata1$second`. So, `hist(mydata1$second[s22_2or4_male])` will use the values of `s22_2or4_male` to subset `mydata1$second` *again*.

The issues can be fixed by

```
s22_2or4_male <- mydata1$gender == 'male' & mydata1$s22 %in% c('2', '4')
hist(mydata1$second[s22_2or4_male])
```

Now, `s22_2or4_male` is a logical vector indicating the selected rows of `mydata1`.

#### Reproducible example using the `mtcars` dataset

```
cyl_6or8_gear4 <- mtcars$gear == 4 & mtcars$cyl %in% c(6, 8)
hist(mtcars$mpg[cyl_6or8_gear4])
```

[image]